# What is the Id and BotId in the manifest.json for a Microsoft Teams bot and where do they come from?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm creating a bot using the bot framework and would like to side-load the bot into Microsoft Teams to test interacting with the bot in a channel.

I'm using the [SimpleBotPackage](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-teams-docs/blob/master/teams/SimpleBotPackage.zip) as a template.

I noticed in the manifest.json, it contains both an `id` (found in the root) and a `botid` (found in `bots` which is found at the root).

What are these values and where do I get them from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `id` and `botid` fields refer to the `MICROSOFT_APP_ID` that you create when your [register your bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/portal-register-bot) on the [Bot Framework Developer Portal](https://dev.botframework.com).

Comment: So they are the same value?

Comment: It is advised to use the same value, yes.

Comment: Not sure why they have different property names, but yes, use the same value for both.

Comment: Thanks for this, I was just wondering the same thing.